# Call dynamic-sidebar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In following code I want to call dynamic-sidebar for wordpress newspaper7 theme

`$buffy .= '`

';

I want to place  dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' );  code between  div but it shows error. Is there any solution plz help

Answer (score 0):

Dont use in between quotations

use like this,

```
$buffy .= dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' );
```

but i'm not sure, its just a try based on your code, because I'm not sure that what and all you are concatenating in the $buffy.